# How to insert Button into TextView sentence?

Tags: android

I have created a `Button` and a `TextView` that contains a sentence. Is it possible to have the `Button` in the sentence?

### For Example

Click this `Button` to go to next page.

Or would you have finish the sentence and put the `Button` after?

#### Button and TextView

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNextPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Next Page"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNextPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click here to go to next page."/>
```

Comment: use HTML for this

Comment: Use two Textviews and place your button in between them.

Comment: You can `implement` `TextView` click event also to manage `Intent`
No need to create `Button` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Either use HTML or end your `TextView` and place a `Button` after it and continue the rest of the sentence with another `TextView`.